# Importing *.dae file with texture to papervision 3D

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, augmented-reality, papervision3d, flartoolkit

I downloaded the exmaples from http://3dvrm.com/flar/, set up a new Flash Builder Project, made some changes and finally I got my cow on top of the marker BUT just the wireframe, not the texture :-(

The Actionscript-Code looks like

```js
  private function setupDAE():void
  {
   //Load collada model
   collada_model = new DAE();
   collada_model.load("model/cow.dae");
   //And setup it's initial parameters
   collada_model.scale = 40;   
   collada_model.rotationX = 90;  
  }
```

The DAE shows

```js
<library_images>
 <image id="texture0" name="texture0">
  <init_from>./Cow.png</init_from>
 </image>
</library_images>
<library_materials>
 <material id="material0" name="material0">
  <instance_effect url="#material0-fx" />
 </material>
</library_materials>
```

Any help?

Comment: You have a folder called model with `cow.dae` right? What happens if you put the png in there too and change `<init_from>` to have `model/Cow.png` instead of just `./Cow.png`... What location do you think `./` is pointing to? Is there a png there? Same exact letters in spelling (maybe its case sensitive, incase if used small "c" for Cow in actual filename)?

Comment: Again: The png-file lies within the model-folder, right next to the dae-file. If I change the path from ./Cow.png to model/Cow.png nothing changes. And yes, the model-filename is cow (small c), the png ist Cow

Comment: If putting Cow.png inside the folder and changing DAE data to match that path isn't working... I'm stumped. If keeping DAE and PNG together and **also** this does not work `<init_from>Cow.png</init_from>` then I'm out. Haven't touched PaperVision in many years now. My final thought : If you run the example files as downloaded (no changes) does the cow keep the texture?

Comment: The downloaded example shows the texture, but after importing the project (and set library pathes and so on) the texture does not show up after compiling. Meanwhile I used another example and this one works so far, well, local... I can run the project, the website shows up, I can see myself and Super Mario is running on the marker, I added a rotating coin. BUT after uploading it on my website, nothing happens: Blank site on chrome and firefox :-(